# Error: 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression on YTD SWITCH/TRUE Logic

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to wrote logic to show the Year to Date values on a P&L alongside in month values.  The logic below works on the monthly calculations but an error is being received when adding in logic to attempt to show the YTD values at the end of the statement.

```
Selected YTD Actuals = 
VAR CURRENTITEM = SELECTEDVALUE( 'P&L Template'[Items (Normalized)])
 return 
 SWITCH( TRUE(),
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Staff Costs", [YTD Total Staff Costs],
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Other Overheads", [Total Other Overheads YTD],
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Spend", [Total Spend YTD],
  CALCULATE(CALCULATE([YTD Cost], FILTER( 'Transaction Data', 'Transaction Data'[CATEGORY] = CURRENTITEM), CALCULATE ([Total Cost], FILTER('Transaction Data', DATESYTD (Dates[Date]))))))
```

Any idea on how to resolve the calculate expression error above?

Appreciate any help,

Bruce

Comment: The problem is with your last statement starting with calculate. I didn't understand what you tried to do there.

Comment: Apologies if the detail is lacking.  The aim if for the statement to work through the P&L Template and calculate a value for each line with the YTD numbers.  The Current item calulcations on lines 5, 6 and 7 are correctly showing the subtotals as expected, the calculate statement at the end is an attempt to show values for the main body of the P&L.  This approach works for the monthly actuals but not with the YTD filter added.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Bruce, Please check the SWITCH syntax. You will see that structure is [Condition],[Result] pairs. If no conditions are satisfied, the first calculate will be performed just like an 'else block'; but you have 2 calculate blocks with no operators(addition, sum, count etc) between them. So your code can't understand exactly how It will handle them. Maybe you expected to write the first calculate as a condition, I don't know.

Comment: For Reference, the below is working for the monthly actuals.  It's the attempt to calculate the YTD numbers as part of the statement that seems to be failing.

Selected Month Actuals = 
VAR CURRENTITEM = SELECTEDVALUE( 'C&D P&L Template'[Items (Normalized)])
 return 
 SWITCH( TRUE(),
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Staff Costs", [Total Staff Costs],
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Other Overheads", [Total Other Overheads],
  CURRENTITEM = "Total Spend", [Total Spend],
  CALCULATE([Total Cost], FILTER('Transaction Data', 'Transaction Data'[CATEGORY] = CURRENTITEM)))

Comment: Yes, That's what I mean. Here : CALCULATE([Total Cost], FILTER('Transaction Data', 'Transaction Data'[CATEGORY] = CURRENTITEM)) is an else block. It means If all conditions are false, then execute this.